# i got an input mistmatch exception in this code can anone help me.(Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException)

Tags: java

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What shoud you Do deposite or withdrowal. then type D for deposite and W for withdrow");
boolean D = scan.nextBoolean();
boolean W = scan.nextBoolean();
try {
    if (D == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount to deposite");
        double amount = scan.nextDouble();
        bank.deposit(amount);
    } else if (W == true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the amount to withdrow");
        double amount = scan.nextDouble();
        bank.withdrow(amount);
    }
} catch(InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("choose the right option");
}
```

Comment: The JavaDoc for InputMismatchException clearly states that it is `[t]hrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.` Is that somehow unclear?\

Comment: You can't read D as boolean. It is a character.

Comment: You are also reading two boolean (should be char) instead of just one.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `Scanner.nextBoolean()` source, you can see following:

```
/**
 * Scans the next token of the input into a boolean value and returns
 * that value. This method will throw <code>InputMismatchException</code>
 * if the next token cannot be translated into a valid boolean value.
 * If the match is successful, the scanner advances past the input that
 * matched.
 *
 * @return the boolean scanned from the input
 * @throws InputMismatchException if the next token is not a valid boolean
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if input is exhausted
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
 */
public boolean nextBoolean()  {
    clearCaches();
    return Boolean.parseBoolean(next(boolPattern()));
}
```

**P.S.** Your code expects `"true"` or `"false"`, but you print e.g. number or something else that cannot be parsed as a `Boolean`.